# FormBuilder group is deprecated with validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the simillar issue as here:

[How do I resolve the error I am encountering using custom Validator syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519768/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-i-am-encountering-using-custom-validator-syntax)

[FormBuilder group is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155217/formbuilder-group-is-deprecated)

I've read that Questions, but the issue still occurs in linter:

> group is deprecated: This API is not typesafe and can result in issues
> with Closure Compiler renaming. Use the `FormBuilder#group` overload
> with `AbstractControlOptions` instead. Note that
> `AbstractControlOptions` expects `validators` and `asyncValidators` to
> be valid validators. If you have custom validators, make sure their
> validation function parameter is `AbstractControl` and not a
> sub-class, such as `FormGroup`. These functions will be called with an
> object of type `AbstractControl` and that cannot be automatically
> downcast to a subclass, so TypeScript sees this as an error. For
> example, change the `(group: FormGroup) => ValidationErrors|null`
> signature to be `(group: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors|null`.
> (deprecation)

And here is my formBuilder:

```
registerForm = this._fb.group({
        firstname: ["", [Validators.required]],
        lastname: ["", [Validators.required]],
        email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ["", [PasswordValidator.strength]],
        confirmPassword: ["", [Validators.required]]
    }, {
        validator: PasswordValidator.confirmed("password", "confirmPassword")
    });
```

And my validator:

```
export class PasswordValidator {
    static confirmed = (controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) => {
        return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
            const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
            const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

            if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.confirmedValidator) {
                return null;
            }

            if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
                matchingControl.setErrors({ confirmedValidator: true });
                return ({ confirmedValidator: true });
            } else {
                matchingControl.setErrors(null);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any idea why? I'm returning the proper object. :/

Comment: It is `validators` and not `validator`

Comment: fixed typo (removed brackets). But it's not the reason

Comment: I mean the error is being thrown because of the line  `validator: PasswordValidator.confirmed("password", "confirmPassword")`

Comment: Well yea, i'm aware of that but, how can I fix that?

Comment: Just add an s... `validators: [PasswordValidator.confirmed("password", "confirmPassword")]`

Comment: It's not solving the issue. It's one validator though.

Comment: Even if it is one or more validators. it has to be validators. with an s, and pass to it an array of one or more items

Comment: That's not true.

Comment: You can re-read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65165250/13680115.  `interface AbstractControlOptions {
  validators?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null
  asyncValidators?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null
  updateOn?: 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'
}` This is directly from the docs. The interface has `validators`, not `validator`

Comment: @OwenKelvin sorry, you've been right. Check my answer.

Answer (score 12):

@OwenKelvin was partially right. It have to be `validators` instead `validator` in formBuilder, even though it's just one validator, sorry Owen again.

But the second problem was in validator. The function should receives `AbstractControl` instead `FormGroup`. So the following code is correct:

```
export class PasswordValidator {
    static confirmed = (controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) => {
        return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
            const input = control.get(controlName);
            const matchingInput = control.get(matchingControlName);

            if (input === null || matchingInput === null) {
                return null;
            }

            if (matchingInput?.errors && !matchingInput.errors.confirmedValidator) {
                return null;
            }

            if (input.value !== matchingInput.value) {
                matchingInput.setErrors({ confirmedValidator: true });
                return ({ confirmedValidator: true });
            } else {
                matchingInput.setErrors(null);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: iam still having the exact same deprecation error after doing what u have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

None of the proposed answers, also in the linked solutions, worked for me...This is how it worked for me:

This is how the validators, including the custom one, are invoked:

```
 this.form = this.fb.group(
      {
      Password:                  ['', { validators:[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]}],
      ConfirmPassword:           ['', { validators:[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]}]
      },
      {validators: this.matchingPasswords('Password', 'ConfirmPassword')}
    )
```

and this is the called validator (in this case placed in the same component)

```
matchingPasswords(Password: string, ConfirmPassword: string) {
    return (controls: AbstractControl) => {
      if (controls) {
        const Password = controls.get('Password')!.value;
        const ConfirmPassword = controls.get('ConfirmPassword')!.value;
        //console.log ("check what is passed to the validator", password, confirmPassword);
        if (Password !== ConfirmPassword) { 
          //this is an error set for a specific control which you can use in a mat-error
          controls.get('ConfirmPassword')?.setErrors({not_the_same: true});  
          //this is the returned error for the form normally used to disable a submit button
          return {mismatchedPassword: true}  
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

- No need (as I read in some threads) for the validation function to be in a separate module
- No need to declare the validator call "as AbstractControlOptions". (which instead would prevent it from working)

To be noted:

1. the call is to validators not validator
2. values are extracted through the .get and need the ! to confirm we're sure they're not null
3. the validator must return a ValidationError or null

Comment: This is the correct answer for Angular 12.
Simply changing "validator:" to "validators:" made the deprecated message go away.

Answer (score 2):

Where you get the error?. I make a [stackblitz with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahevpn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and I can not see it

BTW I don't like so much use setError to "put" an error to a control.

If you're not using mat-error, you can simply ask about form.errors.

If your'e using mat-error you can

- use [custom ErrorStateMatcher](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown) like [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937092/how-to-trigger-the-display-of-mat-error-in-a-mat-form-field-for-a-mat-date-range/62949058#62949058)
- or create a validator over the confirmPassword that take account the
  value of passwrod like [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012294/remove-specific-validator-from-the-formgroup-in-angular/65013492#65013492)
- or use `bind(this)` and ask about this.registerForm.password, see [this another one SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65813583/angular-forms-using-custom-validation-and-a-dynamic-value)

Comment: You have no error because in your stackblitz you have used `validators`. Unfortunately the OP insists on using `validator`, singular because they have only 1 validator